# How can I display formatted markdown?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, uiwebview, markdown, mvvmcross

I'm trying to subclass the `UIWebView` in order to display formatted markdown. Unfortunately I'm having two issues that I can't seem to resolve.

1. I can't seem to dynamically set the height of the view based on the content that is dynamically bound by `MvvmCross`.
2. There is some whitespace at the top of the view that I can't seem to get rid of. Now I understand that this is because iOS is supposed to allow us to scroll the content behind the Navigation bar, but unfortunately I'm not doing my layout that way.

How can I resolve these two issues?

I've attached a screenshot of my current progress, and the code I'm using to generate it.

[image: screenshot with legend]

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using FutureState.BreathingRoom.Touch.Ui.Resources;
using MarkdownDeep;
using MonoTouch.Foundation;
using MonoTouch.UIKit;

namespace FutureState.BreathingRoom.Touch.Ui.Controls
{
    public class FsmUIMarkdownView : UIWebView
    {
        private readonly Markdown _markdownDeep;
        private string _markdown;

        public FsmUIMarkdownView()
        {
            _markdownDeep = new Markdown();
            SetLayoutInfo();
        }

        public FsmUIMarkdownView(RectangleF frame)
            : base(frame)
        {
            _markdownDeep = new Markdown();
            SetLayoutInfo();
        }


        public string Markdown
        {
            get { return _markdown; }
            set
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) || _markdown == value) return;

                _markdown = _markdownDeep.Transform(value);

                var html = new StringBuilder();
                html.Append("<html>");
                html.Append("<head>");
                html.Append("<style type = \"text/css\">");
                html.Append("body {font-family:helvetica;font-size:15; margin:0; padding:0;}");
                html.Append("p {margin:0; padding:5;}");
                html.Append("</style>");
                html.Append("</head>");
                html.Append("<body>");
                html.Append(_markdown);
                html.Append("</body>");
                html.Append("</html>");

                var contentDirectoryPath = Path.Combine(NSBundle.MainBundle.BundlePath, "/");
                LoadHtmlString(html.ToString(), new NSUrl(contentDirectoryPath, true));
                UpdateSize();
                HandleHtmlContentChanged();
            }
        }

        private void UpdateSize()
        {

        }


        private void SetLayoutInfo()
        {
            Layer.CornerRadius = 3;
            Layer.BorderColor = CustomUIColor.breathingroom_borders.CGColor;
            Layer.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White.CGColor;
            ClipsToBounds = true;
        }

        public event EventHandler HtmlContentChanged;

        private void HandleHtmlContentChanged()
        {
            var handler = HtmlContentChanged;
            if (handler != null)
                handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you **have to** use a `UIWebView`?

Comment: @Irene I will use whatever will do the job. I initially chose a UIWebView because it renders HTML.. and I wanted to match my [Android version](https://gist.github.com/ChaseFlorell/7211ffd025f4befcfa9e)

Comment: Ok, I did the same but using a markdown parser and `NSAttributedString`. There are several examples on the web, [this one](http://initwithfunk.com/blog/2013/09/29/easy-markdown-rendering-with-nsattributedstring-on-ios-7/) is a good start. Let me know if you want code samples so that I can write a more proper answer.

Comment: Are you using `SetEdgesForExtendedLayout` anywhere?

Comment: thanks @Irene, I think I got a working solution. https://gist.github.com/ChaseFlorell/7211ffd025f4befcfa9e#file-bindableuimarkdownview